# Value used in comparison not returned, why?

Tags: matlab, select, pixel

In `matlab`, I have [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/53u5k9qntx5lchc/matlab.mat?n=13215274) `.mat` file. If you look inside and double click the cells with vlues `1.000`, you will find that the value that appears is `0.999999999259113` . That's fine. But, when I use for instance the following command:

```
>> sel = find (u2 == 0.999999999259113 );
```

The answer I get is as follows:

```
>> sel

sel =

     5
```

We have more than one `0.999999999259113` value. Don't we? Where are they? What is `5` supposed to be?

Now, when I come to the following function since the `.mat` file is related to [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xohl4i5earnxht8/fuzzysegmented.jpg?n=13215274) image:

```
function s = pixel(x, y)
        pixels = [];
        index = 1;
        for i=1:length(y)
                for j=1:length(y)
                    if y(i,j) == 0.999999999259113;
                        pixels(index) = x(i,j);
                        index = index+1;
                    end
                end
            end
            pixels
        end
```

And, when I run the function I get the following (I: image, u2: the .mat file):

> > pixel(I,u2);

pixels =

```
 []
```

Empty?! What is this supposed to mean?

Any ideas why I'm not getting the expected results, although the commands seem logically working?

Thanks.

Comment: Just like in your previous question, you write a function without ever assigning its return value. Did you consider reading a MATLAB tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking for exact floating point equality, can you set a tolerance? Find values close to 1.0 like this:

```
tolerance = 0.01;
sel = find(abs(u2 - 1.0) < tolerance);
```

Comment: @schelzer. Thanks for your reply. The cells that have the value `1` for instance in another set of cells is: `0.999987149754240`. I caclulated `1-0.999987149754240` to get `0.00001285` I then did the following: `tolerance = 0.00001285` and then `sel = find(abs(u2 - 1.0) <= tolerance);` but got an empty matri as a result. The weired thing is that for instance I have cells with those values `0.999987149754240`. Why don't I get them when I use for instance `find(u1 == 0.999987149754240)`? Aren't they exact values those in the cells?

Comment: @Med-SWEng `0.999987149754240` is not necessarily the exact value stored by the binary, so `==` may not work. Try making your tolerance bigger. Do you find any matches?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
if abs(y(i,j)-)<1e-6
```

instead of

```
if y(i,j) == 0.999999999259113;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did you mean `-1` after `y(i,j)`? Why did you compare it with `1e-6`? `1e-6` equals `−3.281718172`, right?

Comment: I chose 1e-6 arbitrarily. You can make this value smaller if you like. `1e-6` equals 0.000001. Choosing the value you use for this tolerance depends mostly on how close all the values are together and how important it is that you select only those that are very close to 1.